# How do I find out which resolutions are supported in mjpg-streamer?

Tags: webcam

I have mjpg-streamer running on an Orange Pi Zero 2 to stream a USB cam. The default 640x480 works. And when I change the resolution to 1280x720 it works. But I'd like a lower 16:9 resolution, and neither 854x480 or 640x360 works. The log file says `The specified resolution is unavailable, using: width 640 height 480 instead.` Is there a way to figure out what resolutions are supported? And any way I can stream at a low 16:9 resolution?

I'm not sure if this is off-topic because it's an Orange Pi, but the question about mjpg-streamer should apply equally well to a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to see the supported resolutions by using this command after installing `v4l-utils` (substitute in the correct location of the webcam if different):

`v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats-ext`